# Stop number decrease once 0 reached on dice game - Python

Tags: python

I have a dice game on python where you roll the dice twice and it adds the score, when you get an odd number your score decreases by 5. i need to make sure that the score can't go below 0.

I've tried some of the answers to the questions on this site but they didn't work.

I want to make sure score can't go below 0.

Comment: use `if playerTwoPoints > 0:` and `if playerOnePoints > 0:` to control it.

Comment: yes but what should i write after playerOnePoints > 0:

Comment: after `playerOnePoints > 0` you can put your current code. Or you can use `playerOnePoints < 0` to change value to `0` (or bigger) or to end game.

Comment: you repeat almost the same code two times. You could create one code in function and then run it two times with values from different variables. You could also use lists to keep `player_points[0]`,`player_points[1]` `total_score[0]`, `total_score[1]` and `player_number = 0`, player_number =1 ` and then you can use `player_points[player_number]` `player_points[player_number]` to use code in `for` loop.

Comment: every variable create outside functions are global and you don't need `global`. You need only `global` inside function to inform function that you want to use external/global variable instead of local variable - but it is better to send value as parameter in function `function(value1, ...)` instead of using `global value1`.

Comment: it does work this is only one section of the code

Comment: When you call `playerTwoPoints = playerTwoPoints - 5` you need to then see if the number is less than zero, on the next line.

Answer (score 4):

You could use max() like this:

```
playerOnePoints = max(0, playerOnePoints - 5)
playerTwoPoints = max(0, playerTwoPoints - 5)
```

EDIT:
This answers your question, but your code is totally broken, here a working code:

```
import time
import random

total_score1 = 0
total_score2 = 0
rounds = 0

def start_round():
  global total_score1
  global total_score2
  global rounds
  rounds = rounds + 1

  # First player rolls dice
  number = random.randint(1,6)
  number2 = random.randint(1,6)
  playerOnePoints = number + number2
  print("-------------------------------------------")
  print("Round",rounds)
  print("-------------------------------------------")
  print("Player 1's turn    Type 'roll' to roll the dice")
  userOneInput = input(">>> ")
  if userOneInput == "roll":
      time.sleep(1)
      print("Player 1's first roll is", number)
  print("Player 1's second roll    Type 'roll' to roll the dice")
  userOneInput = input(">>> ")
  if userOneInput == "roll":
      time.sleep(1)
      print("player 1's second roll is", number2)
  if playerOnePoints % 2 == 0:
      playerOnePoints = playerOnePoints + 10
      print("Player 1's total is even so + 10 points")
  else:
      playerOnePoints = max(0, playerOnePoints - 5)
      print("player 1's total is odd so -5 points")
  total_score1 += playerOnePoints
  print("-------------------------------------------")
  print("Player 1 has", total_score1, "points")

  # Second player rolls dice
  number = random.randint(1,6)
  number2 = random.randint(1,6)
  playerTwoPoints = number + number2
  print("-------------------------------------------")
  print("Player 2's turn    Type 'roll' to roll the dice")
  userTwoInput = input(">>> ")
  if userTwoInput == "roll":
      time.sleep(1)
      print("Player 2's first roll is", number)
  print("Player 2's second roll    Type 'roll' to roll the dice")
  userTwoInput = input(">>> ")
  if userTwoInput == "roll":
      time.sleep(1)
      print("player 2's second roll is", number2)
  if playerTwoPoints % 2 == 0:
      playerTwoPoints = playerTwoPoints + 10
      print("Player 2's total is even so + 10 points")
  else:
      playerTwoPoints = max(0, playerTwoPoints - 5)
      print("player 2's total is odd so -5 points")
  total_score2 += playerTwoPoints
  print("-------------------------------------------")
  print("Player 2 has", total_score2, "points")

print("-------------------------------------------")
print("Welcome to dice game!")
print("-------------------------------------------")
max_rounds = int(input("Please enter number of rounds: "))
while rounds < max_rounds:
  start_round()
print("-------------------------------------------")
print("End of game")
print("-------------------------------------------")
print("Player 1 has", total_score1, "points")
print("Player 2 has", total_score2, "points")
if total_score1 == total_score2:
  print("It's a tie!")
else:
  print(f"Player {1 if total_score1 > total_score2 else 2} wins!")
```

It is not clear if you want the total score to be the sum of dices plus 10 or minus 5 either if the sum is pair or impair, but I did it that way.

Comment: used this solution but it didn't work still need a working solution, thanks

Comment: @ElijahHiggins10 there you go.

Comment: @ElijahHiggins10 is the solution i posted still not good enough?

Comment: thank you, it does work it just had a beginning bit. Also at the bottom of your code there is an f before the print statement that stops the code from working.

Comment: @ElijahHiggins10 Actually, it is a new feature in Python 3 that allows formatting strings in a more elegant way. You can check it out here https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/ I assumed you were working with python 3, that line in python 2 would traslate to print("Player %s wins!" % (1 if total_score1 > total_score2 else 2))

Comment: oh, it kept giving me syntax error but its ok, i managed to fix it