# score refusing to reset back to zero before displaying

Tags: python

i am trying to create a dice game in python, one of the rules is that the score resets when it goes below zero.

i have tried putting the score reset check in the start, end and dice roll scripts but they always allow for it to go below zero.

```
#import all modules.
import math
import random 
print("successfully imported modules.")
roundno=0
p1score=0
p2score=0
p1dicecomb=0
p2dicecomb=0
p1dice1=0
p1dice2=0
p2dice1=0
p2dice2=0 # assign values.
while roundno < 6:
    if p2score < -1 or p2score == -1:
        p2score = 0
    if p1score < -1 or p1score == -1:
        p1score = 0
    print("round number is round", roundno) #new round always begins on player 1 turn.
    print("player 1")
    p1dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
    p1dice2 = random.randint(1,6)# roll dice using cpu.
    p1dicecomb = p1dice1+p1dice2
    if p1dicecomb % 2 == 0:
        p1score = p1score+10# compare the score to see if odd or even.
    if p1dicecomb % 2 == 1:
        p1score = p1score-5
    print ("score is", p1score)
    print("dice 1 is", p1dice1)
    print("dice 2 is", p1dice2)
    input("press enter to continue rolling dice.")
    print ("player 2")
    if p2score < -1 or p2score == -1:
        p2score = 0
    if p1score < -1 or p1score == -1:
        p1score = 0
    p2dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
    p2dice2 = random.randint(1,6)# roll dice using cpu.
    p2dicecomb = p2dice1+p2dice2

    if p2dicecomb % 2 == 0:
        p2score = p2score+10# compare the score to see if odd or even.
    if p2dicecomb % 2 == 1:
        p2score = p2score-5
    print ("score is", p2score)
    print("dice 1 is", p2dice1)
    print("dice 2 is", p2dice2)
    roundno = roundno+1
    input("press enter to continue rolling dice.")
```

i expect that the code should reset the score back to zero when it goes to -5 but instead it says the score is minus 5.

Comment: At which `print` line is it minus five?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop number decrease once 0 reached on dice game - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56057795/stop-number-decrease-once-0-reached-on-dice-game-python)

Comment: this p2score < -1 or p2score == -1 is the same as p2score <= -1

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing your less than zero check after setting the score.

To test, I've added the following lines:

```py
#Stuff before...
    p2dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
    p2dice2 = random.randint(1,6)# roll dice using cpu.
    p2dicecomb = p2dice1+p2dice2

    print(p2score)
    print(p2dicecomb)

    if p2dicecomb % 2 == 0:
        p2score = p2score+10# compare the score to see if odd or even.
    if p2dicecomb % 2 == 1:
        p2score = p2score-5
    print ("score is", p2score)
```

You will see that the first time `p2score` is printed, it is 0. If `p2dicecomb` is odd then `p2score` becomes 0-5, which is -5!

Rearrange your code slightly to set the check *after* subtracting, e.g.:

```py
import math
import random 
print("successfully imported modules.")
roundno=0
p1score=0
p2score=0
p1dicecomb=0
p2dicecomb=0
p1dice1=0
p1dice2=0
p2dice1=0
p2dice2=0 # assign values.
while roundno < 6:
    if p2score < -1 or p2score == -1:
        p2score = 0
    if p1score < -1 or p1score == -1:
        p1score = 0
    print("round number is round", roundno) #new round always begins on player 1 turn.
    print("player 1")
    p1dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
    p1dice2 = random.randint(1,6)# roll dice using cpu.
    p1dicecomb = p1dice1+p1dice2
    if p1dicecomb % 2 == 0:
        p1score = p1score+10# compare the score to see if odd or even.
    if p1dicecomb % 2 == 1:
        p1score = p1score-5
    if p1score < -1 or p1score == -1:
        p1score = 0
    print ("score is", p1score)
    print("dice 1 is", p1dice1)
    print("dice 2 is", p1dice2)
    input("press enter to continue rolling dice.")
    print ("player 2")

    p2dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
    p2dice2 = random.randint(1,6)# roll dice using cpu.
    p2dicecomb = p2dice1+p2dice2

    if p2dicecomb % 2 == 0:
        p2score = p2score+10# compare the score to see if odd or even.
    if p2dicecomb % 2 == 1:
        p2score = p2score-5

    if p2score < -1 or p2score == -1:
        p2score = 0
    print ("score is", p2score)
    print("dice 1 is", p2dice1)
    print("dice 2 is", p2dice2)
    roundno = roundno+1
    input("press enter to continue rolling dice.")
```

(also you import `math` but don't use it!)

Answer (score 0):

You have two very similar blocks of code:

```
if p1dicecomb % 2 == 1:
    p1score = p1score-5
print ("score is", p1score)
```

then

```
if p2dicecomb % 2 == 1:
    p2score = p2score-5
print ("score is", p2score)
```

There is nothing between subtracting 5 and the print, so if the number is originally 0, it can go to minus five.

You do have a block of code to floor the values at zero:

```
if p2score < -1 or p2score == -1:
    p2score = 0
if p1score < -1 or p1score == -1:
    p1score = 0
```

but this happens BEFORE you subtract 5. 
The lines are executed in order, so you need to move this to floor the value *after* the subtraction.

It might be worth learning how to debug your code, so you can step through one line at a time and see what happens.

Now, some style points. You can pull the repeated parts out into small functions. Or think about steps in the game.

You have to update the score, but you want to ensure the `update` doesn't let the score drop below zero.

You can make a function to do this:

```
  def update (dicecomb, score):
    if dicecomb % 2 == 0:
        score = score+10# compare the score to see if odd or even.
    if dicecomb % 2 == 1:
        score = score-5
    return max(score, 0)
```

and call it in the main loop.
`max` is a standard function that will pick the larger number. If 0 is larger, you won't go negative.

More simply, you can remove all the checks for negative numbers, and just update like this:

```
if p2dicecomb % 2 == 0:
    p2score = p2score+10# compare the score to see if odd or even.
if p2dicecomb % 2 == 1:
    p2score = max(p2score-5, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a matter of order of the operations:

1. You reset the score to 0 if it is negative
2. You roll dices
3. You apply the +10 or -5 operation
4. You print the result, which, at this point, can be negative.

So it is normal if the scores printed are sometimes negatives...

Here is a working example:

```
import random 

roundno = 0
p1score, p2score = 0, 0
p1dice1, p1dice2 = 0, 0
p2dice1, p2dice2 = 0, 0

while roundno < 6:
    print("round number is round", roundno) #new round always begins on player 1 turn.

    print("player 1")
    p1dice1, p1dice2 = random.randint(1,6), random.randint(1,6) # roll dice using cpu.

    # compare the score to see if odd or even.
    if (p1dice1 + p1dice2) % 2 == 0:
        p1score += 10
    else:
        p1score -= 5

    if p1score < 0:
        p1score = 0

    print ("score is", p1score)
    print("dice 1 is", p1dice1)
    print("dice 2 is", p1dice2)

    input("press enter to continue rolling dice.")

    print ("player 2")

    # roll dice using cpu.
    p2dice1, p2dice2 = random.randint(1,6), random.randint(1,6)

    # compare the score to see if odd or even.
    if (p2dice1 + p2dice2) % 2 == 0:
        p2score += 10   
    else:
        p2score -= 5

    if p2score < 0:
        p2score = 0

    print ("score is", p2score)
    print("dice 1 is", p2dice1)
    print("dice 2 is", p2dice2)

    roundno = roundno+1
    input("press enter to continue rolling dice.")
```

Answer (score 0):

after re reading my code, i discovered the code was incorrect.

the correct code was:

```
    p1dicecomb = p1dice1+p1dice2
    if p1dicecomb % 2 == 0:
        p1score = p1dicecomb +10# compare the score to see if odd or even.
    if p1dicecomb % 2 == 1:
        p1score = p1dicecomb-5
```

this fixed the problem for me.